# Group not working in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote a regex for finding id values of html elements:

```
<.+ id\s*=\s*["'](.+)["'].*/?>
```

For most cases it returns id values, but not for this one:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
```

It matches the following group value:

```
__EVENTTARGET" value="
```

instead of the expected `__EVENTTARGET`.

What is wrong in the regex?

Comment: @Mark Byers C# if you mean this, but here it doesn't matter, since all regex test tools return the same.

Comment: @Centro When it comes to Regex, it is always good to mention the "flavor", including .NET, PCRE, Java, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression `(.+)` is "greedy" -- it matches as much as it can.

There are 2 solutions:

"Lazy" (non-greedy): this will match as few characters as possible

```
(.+?)
```

or a better solution, instead of matching `.` you should match `[^'"]`:

```
([^'"]+)
```

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions aren't the best tool for parsing HTML.

You could try making it [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy):

```
<.+ id\s*=\s*["'](.+?)["'].*/?>
                    ^
```

However it can still fail on other examples. It would be better to use an HTML parser, such as [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The '+' is greedy!, gets to the 'id' then after consuming the = then the " it wants more to eat. It can then gorge itself until it reaches the final " and spit that out for you.

Is that Pizza ready yet dear!